# Find the total variation of $[x]-x$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

> Find the total variation of the function $f:[2,4]\to \mathbb R$ defined by $f(x)=[x]-x$.

Here , $f(x)=\begin{cases}2-x &\text{ if } 2\le x<3\\3-x &\text{ if } 3\le x<4\\0 &\text{ if } x=4\end{cases}$

So $f$ is monotone decreasing in $[2,3]$ except $x=3$. Also $f$ is monotone decreasing in $[3,4]$ except $x=4$. So $f$ is of Bounded Variation.
Now , $V_2^4(f)=V_2^3(f)+V_3^4(f)=f(2)-f(3)+f(3)-f(4)=f(2)-f(4)=0.$ So $f$ is constant, a contradiction.

Please show my error and tell me how I find total variation of $f$.

Comment: $f$ is not monotonically decreasing on $[3,4]$.

Comment: Except for x=4.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given an $f:\>[a,b]\to{\mathbb R}^n$ the *total variation* $V$ of $f$ over $[a,b]$ is obtained as follows: Denote by ${\cal P}$ the set of all partitions
$$a=x_0<x_1<x_2<\ldots<x_N=b,\qquad N\geq1\ ,$$
of the interval $[a,b]$. Then $V$ is given by
$$V:=\sup_{\cal P}\sum_{k=1}^N \bigl|f(x_k)-f(x_{k-1})\bigr|\leq\infty\ .$$

Intuitively this means the following: You have to add up all continuous or jump changes of $f$ within the interval $[a,b]$ *positively*, i.e.,  by their absolute value. Looking at the graph of the function $f(x):=\lfloor x\rfloor-x$ we see that we have a continuous decrease by $1$ between $2$ and $3$, then a  $\>+1$ jump at $3$, then a continuous decrease by $1$ between $3$ and $4$, and finally a $\>+1$ jump at $4$. Therefore the total variation we are looking for is $4$.

Comment: Please tell me why we add the jump??

Comment: If I approach through definition then how it will be $4$?